# Change Database in Laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5.4

I have a code that is working but when I switch to different URL the connection I made is back at the default connection, what am I missing ?

```
Route::get('/change-database', function () {
    DB::purge('mysql');

    Config::set('database.connections.test.driver', 'mysql');
    Config::set('database.connections.test.host', 'localhost');
    Config::set('database.connections.test.username', 'root');
    Config::set('database.connections.test.password', '');
    Config::set('database.connections.test.database', 'fdis_two');

    Config::set('database.default', 'test');
    DB::reconnect('test');


    $connection= DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
    return $connection;
});
```

It is working but after going to different routes its getting back to the default connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is working but after going to different routes its getting back to
>   the default connection.

This is because, the `.env` file is not changed in which all of your application's configuration are stored.

Before changing..

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbName
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

In that same route, try to edit the `.env` file and then try to access all the other routes.

After accessing the `/change-database` route, it should reflect:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=newDbName
DB_USERNAME=newUsername
DB_PASSWORD=newPassword
```

---

Or else, you will have to modify your application's code to match something like below: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#using-multiple-database-connections)

> When using multiple connections, you may access each connection via
>   the connection method on the `DB` facade. The name passed to the
>   connection method should correspond to one of the connections listed
>   in your `config/database.php` configuration file:
>
> ```
> $users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);
> ```

Comment: how did u change .env file from controller?